# List data by groups order by date

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I am kind of stuck on a query and could sure use some ideas.
In mysql, I have these fields.
`id, dept, desc, event_date, long_desc`

What I want to do is create a table of the data sorted by dept ordered by date.
So I want the output kinda like this.

```
dept1 -- description -- jan 1

dept1 -- description -- jan 3

dept1 -- description -- jan 5



dept2 -- description -- jan 1

dept2 -- description -- feb 3

dept2 -- description -- march 5

etc..etc..
```

normally, if it's just a few queries..I would just have a few separate queries
like

```
$sql=mysql_query("Select * from blah where blah=blah Order by blah")
```

run my while loop and echo out the `$rows[]` in a table.

But in this case, there are over 200 depts that I need to output.
Is there a way to build that into one query with breaks in between groups?

Comment: What is the data type for the `event_date` column -- string or DATETIME?  Can you provide an example of your expected output?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
    dept, desc, MIN(event_date) 
FROM 
   `table` 
GROUP BY 
   `dept`, `desc`
ORDER BY 
   `date` ASC
```

This allows you to return both the dept and the desc. Make sure your table doesn't have different descriptions for departments that are named the same thing.